# vim match csv line with commas

Tags: regex, vim, regex-greedy

Im having trouble matching X number of commas in a csv file

```
sometext,moretext,moretext2,moretext3,moretext4
```

Im trying to match up to the 3rd comma, any help?

The best I have so far is:

```
/.\{3},
/.\{-},
/.\{0,3},
```

but none of those are doing it for me, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will match upto the third comma

```
/^\([^,]\+,\)\{3\}
```

Comment: Do you need \{3\} or will \{3} do?